# Make not reevaluating dependency variable

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile designed to build a few different programmes. My `SOURCES` and `OBJECTS` depend on `PRODUCT`, which should be the product being built. At the moment, I set `PRODUCT` before listing the dependency on `OBJECTS` on each rule:

```
CORE_LIB    := libcore
SCANNER     := scanner
FLETCHER    := fletcher

PRODUCT     := $(SCANNER)

SOURCE_DIR  := ./src
BUILD_DIR   := ./build
OBJECTS_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/intermediate
PRODUCT_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/product


SOURCES     = $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/$(PRODUCT)/*.c) $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/$(PRODUCT)/*/*.c)
OBJECTS     = $(SOURCES:$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o)

# change PRODUCT based on rule being ran

$(SCANNER): PRODUCT := $(SCANNER)
$(SCANNER): $(OBJECTS)
    # link stuff

$(CORE_LIB): PRODUCT := $(CORE_LIB)
$(CORE_LIB): $(OBJECTS)
    # link stuff
```

However, `OBJECTS` keep being evaluated before `PRODUCT` is set, and never changes based on the rule. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that.  The GNU make manual [states](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html), regarding target-specific variables:

> As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target’s recipe (and in other target-specific assignments).

This means that you can't use target-specific variable values during the expansion of prerequisites, like `$(OBJECTS)`.  Or rather, you can use any variable there but the target-specific value is not available.  Since you set the value of `PRODUCT` globally to be `$(SCANNER)`, which is `scanner`, that's the value that will be used in all prerequisites.

You have multiple options.  You can just define multiple variables, like this:

```
$(SCANNER)_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/$(SCANNER)/*.c) $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/$(SCANNER)/*/*.c)
$(CORE_LIB)_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/$(CORE_LIB)/*.c) $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/$(CORE_LIB)/*/*.c)
```

Then create rules like this:

```
$(SCANNER): $($(SCANNER)_SOURCES:$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o)
        # link stuff
$(CORE_LIB): $($(CORE_LIB)_SOURCES:$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o)
        # link stuff
```

If you have more of these, you could create a macro and use `eval` but I wouldn't bother with the complexity unless you really are going to have a bunch of them.

You can simplify the target definitions a bit using [Secondary Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html), like this:

```
OBJECTS = $$($$@_SOURCES:$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(SCANNER): $(OBJECTS)
        # link stuff
$(CORE_LIB): $(OBJECTS)
        # link stuff
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I decided to go with the secondary expansion solution, works perfectly.